# Handling parameterised order by filters within neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am working on the cypher below but I am not sure how to implement parameterised sorting. I want to sort with the parameters $field and $sort where $field could be: 'species.name', 'species.description', 'species.scientificName', 'monthCount', 'eats'  or 'eatenBy' and $sort is only 'asc' or 'desc'. If either of those values is hardcoded then the cypher runs but when passed as a parameter it fails. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
MATCH (s:Species)
  WHERE toLower(s.name) CONTAINS toLower($search)

WITH s

OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[e:EATS]->(eatsSpecies:Species)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[:EATEN_BY]-(eatenBySpecies:Species)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[:IS_ABOUT]-(image:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:FALLS_UNDER]->(primary:Primary)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(month:Month)

WITH s, eatsSpecies, eatenBySpecies, image, primary, month

WITH s,
     count(DISTINCT eatsSpecies.name) AS eats,
     count(DISTINCT eatenBySpecies.name) AS eatenBy,
     primary,
     image,
     count(distinct month) as monthCount

WITH {
       name:              s.name,
       scientificName:    s.scientificName,
       description:       s.description,
       primary:           case when exists(primary.GUID) then true else false end,
       active:            case when exists(s.active) then s.active else true end,
       months:            monthCount,
       guid:              s.GUID,
       eats:              eats,
       eatenBy:           eatenBy,
       image: case when exists(image.url) then true else false end
     } AS species order by $field $sort

SKIP $skip
LIMIT $limit

RETURN collect(species)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work, by adding a `field` key to the object and inverting the collection before the `SKIP` and `LIMIT`

The suggestion below is pure Cypher. Using apoc, you could also create your dynamic queries.

```
MATCH (s:Species)
  WHERE toLower(s.name) CONTAINS toLower($search)

WITH s


OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[e:EATS]->(eatsSpecies:Species)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[:EATEN_BY]-(eatenBySpecies:Species)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)<-[:IS_ABOUT]-(image:Image)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:FALLS_UNDER]->(primary:Primary)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:MEASURED_BY]->(month:Month)

WITH s, eatsSpecies, eatenBySpecies, image, primary, month

WITH s,
     // add a 'sortField'
     s[$field] AS field,    
     count(DISTINCT eatsSpecies.name) AS eats,
     count(DISTINCT eatenBySpecies.name) AS eatenBy,
     primary,
     image,
     count(distinct month) as monthCount

WITH {
       name:              s.name,
       scientificName:    s.scientificName,
       description:       s.description,
       primary:           case when exists(primary.GUID) then true else false end,
       active:            case when exists(s.active) then s.active else true end,
       months:            monthCount,
       guid:              s.GUID,
       eats:              eats,
       eatenBy:           eatenBy,
       image: case when exists(image.url) then true else false end,
       field:            field
     } AS species ORDER BY species.field 

WITH COLLECT(species) AS sortedSpecies

RETURN CASE $sort 
           WHEN "asc" THEN sortedSpecies[$skip .. $limit]
           ELSE REDUCE(array=[], i IN RANGE(1,size(sortedSpecies)) |
                 array
                 +sortedSpecies[size(sortedSpecies)-i]
              )[$skip .. $limit]
       END AS sortedSpecies
```